# MySQL query to get top 10 point-earners in last week?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, drupal

I'm trying to write a query that returns the user ID's of the top 10 users who gained the most points in the last 7 days on my web app.

I have three tables that, together, have the info I need.

1. `votingapi_votes` table.  It has a record for every up/down vote on a comment or node.
2. `node` table.  It can associate a node ID with a user ID so you can figure out who posted the story getting the votes.
3. `comments` table, which does the same for comments.

I believe I need to write a query that selects every vote on a comment or node from the last week from the votingapi_vote table.

Here's the structure of that table:

- vote_id
- content_type
- content_id
- value
- value_type
- tag
- uid
- timestamp

So I'd SELECT rows of content_type "node" or "comment" with a Unix timestamp greater than time() - 684000.

Then it needs to

2. group these votes by "content_id".
3. Look up the respective "user_id" values for each content_id in the "node" and "comments" tables so we know who made the nodes and comments.
4. Calculate how many points total each user_id gained from his nodes and comments.
5. Sort these user_id's in reverse order and limits it to displaying only the first 10.

Phew.  That seems like what I need to do.  Now what does that actual query look like?

Comment: Does the `value` column represent the summation of votes, or individual votes?  What's the `value_type` column for - if the value is negative or positive?

Comment: Value_type is going to be "points" for all of these. "value" is going to be either "1" or "-1".  So if you sum up all the values for a content_id, you get it's current score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting based on [OMG Ponies' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938553/mysql-query-to-get-top-10-point-earners-in-last-week/1938610#1938610)

```
SELECT x.user_id, SUM(x.total_votes)
    FROM (
        SELECT n.user_id, SUM(vav.value) AS total_votes
            FROM NODE n
            JOIN VOTINGAPI_VOTES vav 
                ON vav.content_id = n.nid
                AND vav.content_type = 'node'
            WHERE vav.timestamp > NOW() - 684000
            GROUP BY n.user_id
        UNION
        SELECT c.user_id, SUM(vav.value) AS total_votes
            FROM COMMENTS c
            JOIN VOTINGAPI_VOTES vav 
                ON vav.content_id = c.cid
                AND vav.content_type = 'comment' 
            WHERE vav.timestamp > NOW() - 684000
            GROUP BY c.user_id
    ) x
    GROUP BY 
        x.user_id
    ORDER BY 
        x.total_votes DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

The problem with the earlier code is that it returns 2 rows per user, 1 for comment, 1 for node. This code will do another `SUM` to aggregate it to just 1 number per user.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  They both appear to return the same results.

Comment: Ok.  Now I'm seeing different results.  This second answer does indeed SUM up the votes for nodes and comments.  However, it's not listing them in proper descending order.  The guy with the most points is currently listed #3 on the list that this query spits out.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT n.user_id,
               SUM(vav.value) 'total_votes'
          FROM NODE n
          JOIN VOTINGAPI_VOTES vav ON vav.content_id = n.nid
                                  AND vav.content_type = 'node'
         WHERE vav.timestamp > NOW() - 684000
      GROUP BY n.user_id
       UNION
       SELECT c.user_id,
              SUM(vav.value) 'total_votes'
         FROM COMMENTS c
         JOIN VOTINGAPI_VOTES vav ON vav.content_id = c.cid
                                 AND vav.content_type = 'comment' 
        WHERE vav.timestamp > NOW() - 684000
     GROUP BY c.user_id) x
ORDER BY x.total_votes DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I think his `uid` refers to the voter id, not the id of the comment-owner

Comment: A few notes:

1. Line 4 should say content_type, I think, not content_id.

2. the "uid" column doesn't tell you who posted the node/comment, but who voted for it.  We need to go grab data from the "node" and "comments" tables to figure out who created each node/comment.

Table structure of "node" table:

nid     uid

Table structure of comments table

cid    uid


cid and nid should have equivalents over in the content_id column of the votingapi_votes table.  matching content_id's of content_type "node" and maching content_id's of content_type "comment".

That's where it gets confusing...

Comment: I think we're really, really close.  I'm getting an error: "Unknown column 'n.user_id' in 'group statement'"

Comment: Change the second `n.user_id` to `c.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views)? I'm pretty sure you can...